# How to get absolute file path from base path and relative containing ".."?

Tags: c#, .net, filepath

```
string basepath = @"C:\somefolder\subfolder\bin"; // is defined in runtime
string relative = @"..\..\templates";

string absolute = Magic(basepath, relative); // should be "C:\somefolder\templates"
```

Can you help me with `Magic` method? Hopefully not too complicated code.

Is there the "`Magic`" method in .NET Framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) class there are a couple of methods which should help:

```
Path.Combine
```

and

```
Path.GetFullPath
```

So:

```
string newPath = Path.Combine(basepath, relative);
string absolute = Path.GetFullPath(newPath);
```

Although the second step isn't strictly needed - it would give you a "cleaner" path if you were printing out say.

Comment: Nice! `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(basepath, relative))` returns what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Path.Combine` does not work in all cases here is a more complex function :-)

```
static string GetFullPath(string maybeRelativePath, string baseDirectory) {
    if (baseDirectory == null) baseDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    var root = Path.GetPathRoot(maybeRelativePath);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(root)) 
        return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, maybeRelativePath));
    if (root == "\\") 
        return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetPathRoot(baseDirectory), maybeRelativePath.Remove(0, 1)));
    return maybeRelativePath;
}
```

`Path.Combine(@"C:\foo\",@"\foo\bar")` returns `@"\foo\bar"` and not as expected `@"C:\foo\bar"`

Comment: "... returns \foo\bar and not as excpected C:\foo\bar" - I don't know why you expect that, since the documentation explicitly states that " If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2."

Comment: \foo\bar is not absolute on Windows missing the drive letter to be absolute - C:\foo\bar is it ^^

Comment: With "expected" I meant "expected by the Magic method" ^^

Comment: Actually `\foo\bar` is considered to be absolute even without the drive letter.  `Path.IsPathRooted` will return `true`.

Comment: You are right BUT if such a path is used you get errors if the current drive is an other as expected. So my method will be aware of this and force to return an unique path independent of current location.